# Syntax error when creating mysql function

Tags: mysql

**mysqlfile.sql**:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS func1;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION func1(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      select * from Employee;
  );
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

executed `source mysqlfile.sql`, got an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
  );
END' at line 4
```

How should I modify the code?

Comment: Functions can not return data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function returns 1 value, as far I can see you want to return a dataset. 
You must create procedure in order to get what you need.

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE getEmployees()
 BEGIN
  SELECT *  FROM employee;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

You can call it by  `call getEmployees();`

Comment: Thank you, it worked great by deleting the semicolon at the end of the `select` code. And I just tested, `function` worked very well in this case if `Employee` only contained one column. There's no need to change it to a `procedure`.

Comment: yes but you needed all the columns as far I can your query..did you test it with multiple rows?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, multiple rows doesn't work with function. :)

Comment: good :) I went through the details in order to make it work..Learned as well

Answer (score 1):

you missed a semicolon after END and have an extra after the select

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS func1;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION func1(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      select * from Employee
  );
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tested, it worked well without the semicolon after `END`

Comment: @MarkZar you are right! for me it works both ways, wouldn't have expected that the semicolon after END would be optional, I have been using it all this time :/.

Comment: @MarkZar  I just checked my DB though, and it seems that both with or without produce the same create code when dumping the function, a rewritten version without the semicolon, so I suppose without it is the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed 'AS' before BEGIN

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS func1;
CREATE FUNCTION func1(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE select_var VARCHAR;
SET select_var = (SELECT * FROM Employee);
RETURN VARCHAR(255);
END$$
```

Hope it'll solve your issue